# How to use default parameter values when extending prototype in typescript?

Tags: typescript

If I have this code

```js
declare global {
    interface Number {
        foo(bool: boolean): number;
    }
}

Number.prototype.foo = function (bool: boolean = false) {
    if (bool) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return this.valueOf();
    }
}

export {};

(100).foo();
```

`tsc` tells me that it's missing the `bool` argument for `(100).foo()`, even though I set a default in the function definition.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Typescript playground link with the above code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeBYAUPEfAJYB2ALiDAGZRgIByArgLZrU4HE-w0ooAFGgEQAXPBEoIIKGQCUEsmw4wA3N2IBfAjvwEW7agDoADjBQVLAT1Mhj-FPAC8fZmTAUSKMvGGiJKRk5Fz5MAGcQeS5CYhIaPyDovFjeeDgKZhhfAAYNVPgteBAISJi0ogys3woACxJw4wA3TGYQAHkaQXl8nj09AhAAD1MUGAocLXyCQQBGHJz5BwFutSA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that there's a default argument is not expressed in the typing. You should do so with a question mark to denote an optional argument:

```
declare global {
    interface Number {
        foo(bool?: boolean): number;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Optional and Default Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can

```
declare global {
    interface Number {
        foo(): number;
        foo(bool: boolean): number;
    }
}
```